# SonarQube for .NET, coverage not shown for all projects

Tags: c#, sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

We have a .NET solution with builds on Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online). The build pushes code coverage data to SonarQube (5.3). We see that for some projects the coverage is lower than expected values (compared with what is found in the raw *.coverage file), for others it is 0 % and yet others have no value at all.

Unfortunately we have no SonarQube experts in our team, but we've tried to change all the settings which seem relevant, with no luck. Where can be start to debug what's going on and what's causing this behavior?

I'll gladly post more info (settings, versions etc.), but I don't know where to start...